# Preventing instanceof and casting in Java

Tags: java, oop, instanceof

How do I avoid using `instanceof` and casting in this situation if I want to have different validators where the method signatures differ?

**Code**

```
for(BatchValidator validator : validators) {
  try {     
    if (validator instanceof BatchErrorValidator) {
      ((BatchErrorValidator<T>) validator).validate(targets);
    } else if (validator instanceof BatchWarningValidator) {
      ((BatchWarningValidator<T>) validator).validate(targets, header);
    }
  } catch (BatchValidationException e) {
    handleImportExceptions(e, header.getSequenceId());
  }
}
```

Comment: You could make them use the same method signatures.

Comment: What is `BatchValidator`?  Is this an interface? Does it give a required signature of the `validate()` method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not make `BatchValidator.validate()` take 2 args: targets and headers. The individual implementations can decide which of the args they need to use.

This way your calling loop just passes the same parameters to each validator and you don't need `instanceof` or any casting.